# Can't use `systemd-cat` inside Docker container

Tags: docker, logging, systemd

I am trying to test logging to `journald` from inside my container.  I want this to work inside a container since our build system runs inside a container.  I need to test a script that uses `journalctl` and I need to generate output for it to parse.  The test script needs to run in the container.

I am launching my container like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home/edge -w /home/edge --log-driver=journald ubuntu /bin/bash 
root@78b56defde31:/home/edge# systemd-cat -t overflow ls /etc
Failed to create stream fd: No such file or directory
```

If I run the same command in the Debian host it works:

```
$ systemd-cat -t overflow ls /etc
$ sudo journalctl | grep overflow
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: acpi
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: adduser.conf
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: adjtime
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: aliases
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: alternatives
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: anacrontab
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: apache2
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: apg.conf
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: apm
Nov 01 08:09:53 nanode64 overflow[9037]: apt
...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing running inside your container other than `bash`.  There is no `journald` running inside the container, and thus no socket for `systemd-cat` to communicate with.  I suspect that your attempt to use `systemd-cat` may stem from a misunderstanding of how the `journald` log driver works.

You're using Docker's `journald` logging driver, which means that anything output by your container to stdout/stderr will show up in your *host* journal.  That is, if you were to run:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/edge -w /home/edge --log-driver=journald ubuntu echo this is a test
```

You would, on the host, see:

```
# journalctl -fl
...
Nov 01 11:45:08 lkellogg-pc0dzzve dockerd[3736]: this is a test
...
```

If you were to show that message using `-o verbose` you would see that it actually contains a variety of additional metadata, such as the container id and container name:

```
# journalctl -fl -o verbose MESSAGE='this is a test'
Wed 2017-11-01 11:48:02.002147 EDT [s=9a99c0d26c3548a2ba6a6416bc37094c;i=15c9cce1;b=3f2b2d45203c485f9fa4373148c81925;m=219ad310e0d;t=55cedcbef19b3;x=6f1641d7b8ebf7ee]
    PRIORITY=6
    _TRANSPORT=journal
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=3f2b2d45203c485f9fa4373148c81925
    _MACHINE_ID=229916fba5b54252ad4d08efbc581213
    _HOSTNAME=lkellogg-pc0dzzve
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _PID=3736
    _COMM=dockerd
    _EXE=/usr/bin/dockerd
    _CMDLINE=/usr/bin/dockerd -G docker --dns 172.23.254.1 --log-driver journald -s overlay2
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/docker.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=docker.service
    _SELINUX_CONTEXT=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
    MESSAGE=this is a test
    CONTAINER_ID=5d20a635fcff
    CONTAINER_ID_FULL=5d20a635fcff5c57212a65d5d0ebd77f3fd9529a8fd4fe6b718238877ecf5173
    CONTAINER_NAME=optimistic_easley
    CONTAINER_TAG=5d20a635fcff
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1509551282002147
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem but can I connect to the `journald` socket on the host from inside the container?

Comment: Sure, you can expose the journald socket by adding `-v /run/systemd/journal:/run/systemd/journal` to your `docker run` command line, but in most situations your best option is just to reply on the standard docker logging behavior.

Comment: I need access to the logs from inside the container.  I may be mistaken, but I don't think I can do this using "standard docker logging behavior".

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to show what you're actually trying to do? That would help make sure the answers are useful. Exposing the journald socket as in my previous comment will let you log *to* journald, but won't give you access to the logs.

Comment: I've updated the question.  Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: If I add `-v /run/log/journal:/run/log/journal` in addition to the `-v` option you suggested and I run the container as `root` then I can get the logs.  Our build system doesn't run the containers as root so I have to find a solution to that but that's a different issue.